# Searching a key in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a building a chrome extension, I have following data as

```
var data = {}
data["Five, ok"] = "another one"
chrome.storage.sync.set(data)

chrome.storage.sync.get(function(content){console.log(content)})


>> {'Five, ok': "Another one ", 'ok, done': "New one"}
```

This can grow bigger with many values. (Key is a comma separated value).

I want to get all keys which include (2 different cases, this are user give values) 
1. ok 
2. done

this values are dynamic, what is the best way to achieve this in JavaScript/ jquery

Comment: This is invalid JSON

Comment: provide a correct json.

Comment: this is actually the content I got from executing this function  chrome.storage.sync.get(function(a){console.log(a)})

Comment: can't possibly be because that isn't a valid object shown. Please note that json and javascript objects are not the same thing either. Question has nothing to do with json

Comment: Updated the question, new to chrome extension development

Comment: proper javascript representation for that object should be `{'Five, ok': "Another one ", 'ok, done': "New one"}` ... keys with special characters require quotes. Data structure could be greatly improved if you want to iterate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(function(content) {
    var keys = Object.keys(content);
    var keysOK = keys.filter(function(key){ return key.search(/\b(ok|done)\b/i) });
    console.log(keysOK);
});
```

- `/\b(ok|done)\b/i` finds the keys containing either `ok` or `done`
- `/\bok\b/i` finds the keys containing `ok`
- `/\bdone\b/i` finds the keys containing `done`
- The `i` at the end makes the search case-insensitive.

As @charlietfl commented it's not efficient. However chrome.sync doesn't allow more than [100kB of data](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties) anyway so it's probably not an issue.